# How to run an .exe when email with certain keywords is sent out

Tags: c#, email, jenkins, remote-server

There are 2 machines:
-Laptop
-Server (contains .exe file that runs tests)

Goal Scenario: Laptop sends out an email with keywords "RUNTESTING". This triggers the server to run the .exe file, wait for testing to finish, then email back results to same email address.

Is this possible? I am looking for something that can access outlook and "read" emails from that specific person.

I already set up Jenkins but that doesn't help with email scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience with jenkins, but you can accomplish this with C# using a library called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). More specifically you could enclose code which searches for the your keyword in the mail subject, within a timed loop that iterates every 5 minutes or so.

You would also have to delete matching messages or use some sort of log to avoid duplicate matches.

You could also use this code to start the .exe and wait for it to finish before sending the results (which you can do with MailKit):

```
Process.Start(); 
Process.WaitForExit();
```

Something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Net.Mail;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;

void test()
    {
        const int period = 1000 * 60 * 5; //5 minutes
        do
        {
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect(serverAddress, 993, true);
                client.Authenticate(username, password);
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                SearchQuery query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains("RUNTESTING");
                foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query))
                {
                    var process = Process.Start("testing.exe");
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        var message = new MimeMessage();
                        message.Subject = "Testing complete";
                        client.Connect(serverAddress, port, false);
                        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                        client.Authenticate(username, password);
                        client.Send(message);
                        client.Disconnect(true);
                    }
                }
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(period);
        } while (true);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how I would import that library into Visual Studio 2013? I am new to C# and VS

Comment: I'm not sure if 2013 has NuGet support but if it's the same it will be under project>manage NuGet packages. There you can search for MailKit and add it easily. Otherwise, you should download the solution from the Github I linked and compile it in visual studio. Then you can add a reference to the DLL file generated by Project>Add reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a mailbox just as Outlook does, and wouldn't need to access Outlook directly.

There are POP3 and IMAP libraries available for most languages. Your program could be scheduled to run once every ten minutes (or more frequently if necessary) using cron on Linux or Windows Task Scheduler on Windows. When ran, it would parse new mail that it hasn't seen, and when "RUNTESTING" is seen in a subject or body, perform an action.

There might be commercial products available to automate tasks on email conditions, however, writing what you describe should not be a particularly large project. I'd start by looking into and trying IMAP libraries for C# if that is your preferred language.